# Error while installing VMWare plugin for TeamCity

Tags: vmware, teamcity

I'm trying to install VMWare plugin for TeamCity. I followed all steps from

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Cloud-VMWare+plugin

to the point. However, when I try to run the client via command line, i just get this message:

> C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\MyVMs>java -jar cloud-vmware-client.jar
>   /server:http://10.1.100.33 /vmrun: "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\VMware\VMware VIX\" /store: "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\MyVMs\" 
>   [/maxInstances:10} Loading libraries from:
>   C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\MyVMs\lib Attempt to read TeamCity internal
>   property "teamcity_logs" before initialization ! Default value is
>   used. Callee:
>   jetbrains.buildServer.log.LogInitializer.initLogDir(LogInitializer.java:266)
>   Using logs directory C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\MyVMs..\logs Attempt to
>   read TeamCity internal property "log4j.configuration" before
>   initialization! Default value is used. Callee:
>   jetbrains.buildServer.log.LogInitializer$
>   3.configure(LogInitializer.java:165) Usage: tool.exe /server: /vmrun: /store:
>   [/silent] [/maxInstances:]

and nothing happens.

Have I missed something maybe?